# Save no capture data in mitmweb

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm running mitmproxy on Windows (mitmweb.exe). There is any way to set option not to store captured data?

The problem is in memory consumption when mitmproxy is running long time.
[image]

Comment: So far it seems no option to store flows data on disk instead of memory https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3302.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any solution, so I have wrote a very simple proxy program using https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy