# MemoryError in mitmweb: Limit flows?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, mitmproxy

Is there a setting in mitmweb that limits the number of flows kept in memory? Ideally I’d like to keep only the captures of the last 1-3h. My current solution is restarting mitmweb via cronjob, but it feels very hackish and cuts off the flows at that point.

Seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817518/save-no-capture-data-in-mitmweb), but the solution there does not work for me.